# Market risk in Tier 1 capital of a bank

Tags: banking-regulations, central-banking

The common stock of the bank is considered to be a part of the Tier 1 capital, but it is also subject to market risk. The [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/common-equity-tier-1-cet1.asp) definition distinguishes between Tier 1 and Tier 3 capital by the latter carrying market risk.

Why is common stock of the bank considered to be a Tier 1 capital? Wouldn't during a liquidity event the value of the common stock of the bank also take a hit?

Comment: The explanation in that Investopedia article is of poor quality. DIsregard it.

Comment: @nbbo2 I also looked at this [BIS](https://www.bis.org/fsi/fsisummaries/defcap_b3.pdf) summary and I am not able to understand why is the common stock of the bank considered to be Tier 1 capital in the face of market risk. The entire CET1 could just be the common stock of the bank and in a crisis event could be worth zero.

Comment: The higher the CET1 before the crisis the bigger the losses the bank can take and still survive (still have positive net worth), which is precisely the definion of **bank capital**. Of course no one can have infinite capital and survive all possible contingencies.

Comment: @nbbo2 Thanks! I get it now. So there is an assumption of efficiency in that market participants assign a value to the stock of the bank which is correlated with the bank capital. So a loss of confidence in the market would lead to a bank run, and conversely a bank run would lead to a loss in market value.